# Advanced sorting of a multidimensional array in PHP

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

I have looked through all the answers about sorting multidimensional arrays in PHP on Stack Overflow, but none have directly answered my question.

From the various answers I have understood that I should be using either the php `usort` function or the php `array_multisort` function, but I am not sure how to apply these to my very specific array structure:

Here is my variable `$array`:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [field1] => 10
            [field2] => 100
            [field3] => 100
            [subarray] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [field1] => 10
                            [field2] => 100
                            [field3] => 100
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [field1] => 10
                            [field2] => 100
                            [field3] => abcORDERBYTHIS
                        )

                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [field1] => 10
            [field2] => 100
            [field3] => 100
            [subarray] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [field1] => 10
                            [field2] => 100
                            [field3] => 100
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [field1] => 10
                            [field2] => 100
                            [field3] => ghiORDERBYTHIS
                        )

                )

        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [field1] => 10
            [field2] => 100
            [field3] => 100
            [subarray] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [field1] => 10
                            [field2] => 100
                            [field3] => 100
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [field1] => 10
                            [field2] => 100
                            [field3] => defORDERBYTHIS
                        )

                )

        )

)
```

I would like to be able to sort this array by `field3` of the **last** array in `subarray`. Accessing this element is easy enough with the php `end` function like so:

```
<?php
foreach($array as $array_single){
    foreach(end($array_single['subarray']) as $sub_array){
        echo $sub_array;
    }
}
?>
```

And from now on I'm stuck in how to specifically sort this multidimensional array alphabetically so that we get the following result:

- `$array[0]` - Remains on top because the `field3` value is `abcORDERBYTHIS`
- `$array[2]` - Jumps into the middle because the `field3` value is `defORDERBYTHIS`
- `$array[1]` - Is now at the bottom because the `field3` value is `ghiORDERBYTHIS`

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Such advanced array sorting is often DIY.

Comment: Ouch @JasonMcCreary - not what I want to hear! ;)

Comment: Sorry. While PHP over 100 array functions, there's no silver bullet. That's not to say a combination may not provide you what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code:

```
$array = Array();

$arraytemp['field1'] = 10;
$arraytemp['field2'] = 100;
$arraytemp['field3'] = 100;
$arraytemp['subarray'][0]["field1"] = 10;
$arraytemp['subarray'][0]["field2"] = 100;
$arraytemp['subarray'][0]["field3"] = 100;
$arraytemp['subarray'][1]["field1"] = 10;
$arraytemp['subarray'][1]["field2"] = 100;
$arraytemp['subarray'][1]["field3"] = "abcORDERBYTHIS";

$array[] = $arraytemp;

$arraytemp['field1'] = 10;
$arraytemp['field2'] = 100;
$arraytemp['field3'] = 100;
$arraytemp['subarray'][0]["field1"] = 10;
$arraytemp['subarray'][0]["field2"] = 100;
$arraytemp['subarray'][0]["field3"] = 100;
$arraytemp['subarray'][1]["field1"] = 10;
$arraytemp['subarray'][1]["field2"] = 100;
$arraytemp['subarray'][1]["field3"] = "ghiORDERBYTHIS";

$array[] = $arraytemp;

$arraytemp['field1'] = 10;
$arraytemp['field2'] = 100;
$arraytemp['field3'] = 100;
$arraytemp['subarray'][0]["field1"] = 10;
$arraytemp['subarray'][0]["field2"] = 100;
$arraytemp['subarray'][0]["field3"] = 100;
$arraytemp['subarray'][1]["field1"] = 10;
$arraytemp['subarray'][1]["field2"] = 100;
$arraytemp['subarray'][1]["field3"] = "defORDERBYTHIS";

$array[] = $arraytemp;

// Sort the multidimensional array
usort($array, "custom_sort");

// Define the custom sort function used in usort
function custom_sort($a,$b) {
    return strcmp($a['subarray'][1]["field3"], $b['subarray'][1]["field3"]);
}
```

Comment: Thanks Fabio! This works perfectly as expected. I am marking this as the correct answer. Thanks for the quick response !!!